# What is the standard way to loop over the elements of multi-dimensional array of an object?

Tags: system-verilog

```
foreach(a.b[i]) begin
    foreach(a.b[i][j]) begin   
       foreach (a.b[i][j].c[k]) begin  
       d = a.b[i][j].c[k];  
end 
  end  
    end
```

a is a class, b is an object of a separate class e in class a, c is a member of class e which is being accessed through b and d is variable being assigned the value present in c.

I am getting a syntax error in first line itself. What is the correct way to loop over the elements of the multi-dimensional array b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per section 12.7.3 of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM, the proper syntax to loop over your multi-dimensional array is:

```
foreach(a.b[i, j]) begin
  foreach (a.b[i][j].c[k]) begin
    d = a.b[i][j].c[k];
  end
end
```